# Alarm Manager not functioning when app is closed

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm going on with an alarm application, but i found a question which the alarm manager does not function when the app is closed in some devices. But when i enabled the application to run in background in setting, the alarm works properly.

My question is, is there any way to bring user to setting and enable the app to run in background.

Answer (score 0):

Send the following intent:

```
    val i = Intent()
    i.action = Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS
    i.data = Uri.parse("package:com.your.package")
```

obviously, replace "com.your.package" with your app's package name